# Ackermann function iterative-recursive form in C

Tags: algorithm, c

I am trying to write the Ackermann function iterative in m and recursive in n. I got to this point where the code I provided below work for all values below Ack(5,0) but it overflows after this value. I am not sure where and I am not sure how to optimize it.
What I am trying to achieve is this:

$$Ack(m,n)=Ack(m-1,Ack(m,n-1))=Ack(m-2,Ack(m-1,Ack(m,n-1))-1)=Ack(m-3,Ack(m-2,Ack(m-1,Ack(m,n-1))-1)-1)$$
and so on.

Here is the code:

```
unsigned long long Ackermann_itm_recn(int m, unsigned long long n){
    unsigned long long Ack=0;
    if (m==0){
        Ack = n+1;
    }
    else if(n==0){
        Ack = Ackermann_itm_recn(m-1,1);
    }
    else{
        Ack=Ackermann_itm_recn(m-1,Ackermann_itm_recn(m,n-1));
        for(int i=2;i<=m-2;i++){
            Ack= Ackermann_itm_recn(m-i,Ack-1);
        }
    }
    return Ack;
}

int main(){
    printf("%lld \n", Ackermann_itm_recn(4,0));
}
```

Comment: This would probably a better question for SO and not Code Review. Code Review is all about reviewing existing working code and not to solve specific problems.

Comment: ok thanks, should i delete the problem?

Comment: Yes, I think that would be best unless you want to rephrase your question to just ask for a code review and general improvement tips.

Comment: I changed the question

Comment: Well, the Ackerman function grows extremely quickly, `A(5, 0)` is the only value you can compute in 64 bit for `m=5`, for `m=4` you can compute `n=0,1`, for `m=3` you can compute `n=0..61` - check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function

Comment: I find no programming error with the code presented. The way to compute the Ackermann-Péter function is stated clearly. Asking *how to optimize*, do the same for the goal of improvement.

Comment: @greybeard OK..

Answer (score 3):

Only small stuff, no optimization suggestions.

**Save time, enable all warnings**

Mismatched specifier.
Consider dropping spaces before a `'\n'`.

```
// printf("%lld \n", Ackermann_itm_recn(4,0));
printf("%llu\n", Ackermann_itm_recn(4,0));
```

**Negative `m`?**

Code goes [off the rails](https://medium.com/@88pwt/going-off-the-rails-dcbb4749e34e) when `m < 0`.  Perhaps an `assert(m >= 0)` or use `unsigned`:

```
// unsigned long long Ackermann_itm_recn(int m, unsigned long long n){
unsigned long long Ackermann_itm_recn(unsigned m, unsigned long long n){

// Avoid trouble when m == 1
// for(int i=2;i<=m-2;i++){
for(unsigned i = 2; i + 2 <= m; i++) {
```

**`uintmax_t`?**

Common today that `uintmax_t` and `unsigned long long` are the same range, yet why not use a potential wider type?

```
#include <inttypes.h>
uintmax_t Ackermann_itm_recn(int m, uintmax_t n) {
  ...

printf("%ju\n", Ackermann_itm_recn(4,0));
```

Answer (score 3):

### Declaring `main()` instead of `main(void)` is Incorrect (Until C23)

This is a deprecated way of declaring a K&R-style variadic function.  C23 will redefine this to mean the same thing as `main(void)`, as C++ has done for decades.

C17 says that the two allowed definitions are `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` (or compatible).  This isn’t just language-lawyering either: on some implementations, K&R-style functions have a different calling convention.

### Scalars that Cannot be Less than 0 Should be `unsigned` Types

You declare `int m`, but this form of the Ackermann function is only defined for non-negative integers.

Also, if the parameters should not be modified, declare them `const` in the function definition.  (There are no function prototypes in this program, but it is not necessary there.)

### Use a 128-bit Type if You Have One

Your values are overflowing `unsigned long long int`, but there is no portable 128-bit type in C17.

Adding `uintmax_t` to the Standard turned out to be a mistake, because implementations weren’t able to change it and break their ABI, but also weren’t allowed to have any type wider than it.  This prevented many implementations from having an unsigned 128-bit type.

C23, however, is going to redefine `uintmax_t` so that there can be integers wider than it.  C23 will also allow

```
typedef unsigned _BitInt(128)  u128
```

for a portable, 128-bit unsigned type.

### Use Standard Naming Conventions

Function names are not normally capitalized in C, even when they happen to be named after a person or proper noun.

### You Can Optimize With a Tail-Recursive Implementation

This isn’t the conventional way to write C, but several compilers, including Clang, ICX and ICPX, support an extension that tells the compiler to always perform tail-call optimization.  I often use it with this boilerplate:

```c
#if defined(__clang__) || defined(__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER )
#  define MUSTTAIL __attribute((musttail))
#else
#  define MUSTTAIL /**/
#endif
```

This makes `MUSTTAIL return ackermann_tr(m-1, 1);` expand to the proper compiler extension to force tail-call elimination on compilers that support it, or to a plain `return` statement on compilers that don't.

With Clang 17.0.1 using `-std=c17 -march=x86-64-v3 -O3`, this tail-recursive version:

```c
#if defined(__clang__) || defined(__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER )
#  define MUSTTAIL __attribute((musttail))
#else
#  define MUSTTAIL /**/
#endif

unsigned long long ackermann_tr( const unsigned m, 
                                 const unsigned long long n
                               ) {
    if (m == 0) {
        return n+1;
    } else if (n == 0) {
        MUSTTAIL return ackermann_tr(m-1, 1);
    } else {
        MUSTTAIL return ackermann_tr(m-1, ackermann_tr(m, n-1));
    }
}
```

generates the following code:

```
ackermann_tr:                           # @ackermann_tr
        mov     rax, rsi
        test    edi, edi
        je      .LBB1_6
        push    rbx
        mov     ebx, edi
        jmp     .LBB1_2
.LBB1_3:                                #   in Loop: Header=BB1_2 Depth=1
        mov     eax, 1
        dec     ebx
        je      .LBB1_5
.LBB1_2:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        test    rax, rax
        je      .LBB1_3
        dec     rax
        mov     edi, ebx
        mov     rsi, rax
        call    ackermann_tr
        dec     ebx
        jne     .LBB1_2
.LBB1_5:
        pop     rbx
.LBB1_6:
        inc     rax
        ret
```

Particularly note that only the nested call to `ackermann_tr` within the `else` case needs a `call` instruction, and all others are optimized by jumps.  For the original implementation, the compiler with the same settings generates the code:

```
Ackermann_itm_recn:                     # @Ackermann_itm_recn
        push    rbp
        push    rbx
        push    rax
        mov     rax, rsi
        test    edi, edi
        je      .LBB0_3
        mov     ebx, edi
        test    rax, rax
        jne     .LBB0_4
        mov     eax, 1
        dec     ebx
        je      .LBB0_3
.LBB0_4:
        lea     ebp, [rbx - 1]
        dec     rax
        mov     edi, ebx
        mov     rsi, rax
        call    Ackermann_itm_recn
        mov     edi, ebp
        mov     rsi, rax
        call    Ackermann_itm_recn
        cmp     ebx, 4
        jl      .LBB0_7
        add     ebx, -3
.LBB0_6:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        lea     edi, [rbx + 1]
        dec     rax
        mov     rsi, rax
        call    Ackermann_itm_recn
        dec     ebx
        jne     .LBB0_6
.LBB0_7:
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
.LBB0_3:
        inc     rax
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Note that this has significantly more instructions and requires more `call` instructions, each of which has to create a new stack frame.

GCC and MSVC do not support the `musttail` compiler extension, but GCC performs the optimization without needing a hint.  MSVC does not.

[You can try out the code on Godbolt.](https://godbolt.org/z/zjb1abW54)

Comment: Just as a comment: For Ackermann, 128 bit won't really get you much further than 64 bit. Going from `A(4, 1)` to `A(4, 2)` for example goes from requiring 16 bits to requiring 65536 bits

Comment: `int main()` is fine.  C17 says that the two allowed definitions as well as "or in some other implementation-defined manner.". C99/C11 specs use `int main()` in example code.  A function _definition_ using `f()` has been the same as `f(void)` since, IIRC, C99.  What has changed in C17 relates to `f()` as a _declaration_, something OP is not doing here.

Comment: "Function names are not normally capitalized in C" is a truism for standard library functions. Yet much user code uses uppercase in names.  That is a style issue.

Comment: "because implementations weren’t able to change it and break their ABI" sounds like a self imposed problem not of the language, but of the user code.  One can certainly write code using `(u)intmax_t` and deal with growth.  Same thing happened with `long` as 32 then 64 bit.  What is tricky about `(u)intmax_t` is that is the type used by the pre-processor and assuming that is 64-bit leads to issues.

Comment: "parameters should not be modified, declare them const." is a style issue. In select cases, it is useful in function definitions, yet at the cost of some clutter. In function declarations, it adds no value, just clutter. Note the standard C library does not use `const` on any function parameter in the declarations. (Of course `const` is used on the pointed to types)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica To language-lawyer a bit, §6.7.6.3.15 says, “If one type has a parameter type list and the other type is specified by a function definition that contains a (possibly empty) identifier list, both shall agree in the number of parameters, and the type of each prototype parameter shall be compatible with the type that results from the application of the default argument promotions to the type of the corresponding identifier.” That means that if you declare `int foo(void)` and define `int foo() {`, the two will be compatible. But `main` is not required to work that way!

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I respectfully disagree that declaring parameters `const` is just a style issue. It tells the compiler that, when a parameter is modified, that’s a bug. In some cases, it also enables optimizations.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Also with respect, you misunderstand the C committee’s rationale for changing `uintmax_t`. If an implementation defines `uintmax_t` as 64-bit, it cannot change that later without breaking the ABI (such as shared library binaries). But implementations could not have any scalar type wider than `uintmax_t`. This was preventing real-world compilers from making the `_uint128_t` type they already support an official type.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Finally, I agree that my advice on case conventions is purely stylistic.

Comment: @Davislor With respect, `main()` is special, yet more than 2 forms are available per the implementation.  Re: `main()`, `main()` is not required to not work that way either.  In the case of function _declarations_, `const` parameters do not  "tells the compiler that, when a parameter is modified, that’s a bug", just add noise.  ABI issue describe also prevents `int, long, long long` from moving from 32,32 or 64,64 to 32,64,128, yet `long long` is not a mistake.  ABI breaking survived `int` as 16 going to 32.  Similar mitigation strategies can apply for `(u)intmax_t`.  UV for good discourse.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I think there’s some misunderstanding. There are no function prototypes in this program, only function definitions, where `const` qualifiers do make a difference. Defining `int main() {` is not technically well-formed (although I can’t think of a platform on which it would fail, either, and C23 will allow it). With any other function, `int foo()` being a K&R-style unprototyped function, and not a synonym for `int foo(void)`, is a huge gotcha.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Finally, you’re correct that no other type can be widened without breaking the ABI, either. The reason the C Standard Committee decided this was a problem for `uintmax_t` and not other types, and are going to change the requirements to address it, is that C99–C17 do not allow integer types wider than `uintmax_t`. The Standard doesn’t say that about `long long int`, so it doesn’t get in the way of adding 128-bit integers on platforms that support them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149191/discussion-between-chux-reinstate-monica-and-davislor).